# Why I can't get the TTY's?

Tags: tty

So I just installed ubuntu minimal with gdm and openbox and I can boot into Openbox just fine, but I obviously need to install other packages which I can do from just the blank Openbox DE. I know that you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> after grub to open to cli, but it only stays up for a second and then it just continues onto gdm and I can' do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After logging in (or just before), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>. Then enter your login and password and run

```
sudo stop gdm
```

This will enable the CLI.

The second way is holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the boot and choosing *Recovery Mode*. Then you should select *Drop to root shell with networking*.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot you have to wait until the GDM has already loaded to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a TTY. You can also edit the grub entry and add `text` at the end to disable the GUI based boot.